# NodeJS and Knex - tables are not created automatically

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite

I have NodeJS application base on SQLite. My problem is that DB is not being initialized on startup. No tables are created but my queries run fine (with no such table error).
Here is my config.js contents. This file is called whenever database is neeeded.

```
var knex = require('knex')({
    client: 'sqlite3',
    connection: {
        filename: "db.sqlite"
    },
    useNullAsDefault: true
});

//var bookshelf = require('bookshelf')(knex);
//bookshelf.plugin('registry');

module.exports = {
    "port": process.env.PORT || 3000,
    "secretKey": "MyOwnSecretKey",
    "knex": knex
    //"bookshelf": bookshelf
};
```

Now in my user.js file I am calling this with the following:

```
var config = require('../../config');
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs');

var knex = config.knex;
knex.schema.createTableIfNotExists('users', function(table) {
    table.increments();
    table.string('name', 128);
    table.string('username', 128);
    table.string('password');
    //table.string('email', 128);
    //table.string('role').defaultTo('admin');    
    table.timestamps();
});

//var bookshelf = config.bookshelf;
var bookshelf = require('bookshelf')(knex);
bookshelf.plugin('registry');

var User = bookshelf.Model.extend({
    tableName: 'users',
    ...
```

when I try to call any method getting or creating data I have error that the table does not exist. I have moved table creation part to my server.js file too but it also didn't create the table (although debugging show that it should).
What is the catch here? Or perhaps there is a better way to create tables that this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`knex` has weird APIs. The query is not executed unless you call the `then` method which can be considered as an exec method. So try calling the `then` method on the migration query.

Note that the API is async and you should wait until the tables are created before querying the tables. You shouldn't put your migration code in your model files after all. `knex` has a CLI for generating and executing migration files!

Create a folder for database migrations and then use the `$ knex migrate:make file_name_goes here` command for creating a migration file. Then you can use the `$ knex migrate:latest` command for executing the migration files.

Comment: this is it, it works. I don't get the last suggestion actually but I will work on it. Thanks.